# Is it term paper / thesis season or something?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed we are getting a lot of questions recently on diff-in-diff from new users.

I assume a lot of these are for some basic undergrad student term papers or final theses, but am curious what might be driving this sudden influx.

Anyone have any insight, especially those of you in academia or familiar with the academic cycle?

And if so, can we or should we even prepare for these cycles in some way? Like bumping/sticky-ing certain answers to basic common questions around this time of year? Since a lot of the questions are definitely related to previous answers, at least indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

I am in academia, and other than DiD becoming quite popular empirical technique I am not really aware of any cycle regarding this. Probably just an accident of perhaps multiple students taking econometrics course discovering site at the same time through word of mouth (one student in class might have gotten good advice and told others).

If there are similar questions you can vote to close as duplicate. That is the right thing to do, or if you want to be more gentler put a reminder in comments that users are expected first search other answers on this site.

Bumping certain answers would require involvement of someone from stack exchange, we moderators can't do that, I do not believe there is some tool even for CMs to do it automatically based on some criteria, it would likely have to be done manually.